# I have a Function which sometimes returns True, sometimes False. How do I count the Trues and False?

Tags: python, function, count

TLDR:
add

print(hundred())

to this code, and you will see the function returns sometimes True, sometimes False. How do I count these with a loop? If I use an if statement, it returns all True or all False over all iterations... Inside a loop the function is either True True True True True  or False False False False... which makes no sense to me.

I have battled over this for 3 days. It's about a Coin Flip problem from Automate Boring Stuff. Been "programming" for 1 month or so with no prior exp.

So, this is the function, that returns False or True. I need to be able to count them somehow.
So, if the function is called 10 times (iterations variable), I need for each time it returns True to count them. I tried while loops, if statements, for loops, I don't get why it doesn't work... Really stuck.

```
import random


headtails = ['H', 'T']
resultlist = []
current = 1
total = []
count = 0
countlist = []
tries = 1


def hundred():
    global resultlist, current, total, count, countlist, tries, headtails
    for i in range(100):
        x = random.choice(headtails)
        resultlist.append(x)
        if resultlist[i] != resultlist[i-1]:
            current = 0
        else:
            current = current +1
            if current >= 6:
                total.append(current)
                current = 0
    if len(total) != 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# function ends here, now we need to call it and count Trues and Falses. 
# How do I do it? This doesn't work:

iterations = 0
number_of_true = 0
overalls = 0

while iterations < 10:
    iterations += 1

    if hundred():
        number_of_true += 1
        overalls += 1
    elif hundred() is False:
        overalls += 1
print(number_of_true, overalls)
```

OK I found the problem but not solution. If you call the function many times

```
print(hundred())
print(hundred())
print(hundred())
print(hundred())
```

they all going to be either False or True, which means they all point to the same value in memory. So, it's not possible to iterate its results in any way... damn, what do I do. I get a new result only when I run/stop program.

Comment: You never reset `total`, so once `hundred()` returns True, it will forever more return True every time you call it.

Comment: Hello Tom. It can't be a number, it must be a Boolean returned. I need to check whether something happened there. Sometimes a True, sometimes a False and I need to count them and it doesn't work. If we increase iteration to 100, it should be something like 70 and 100 printed at the end... Instead I get 0 100 or 100 100 which makes no sense to me

Answer (score 1):

You're making two calls to `hundred()` each time you want to check if it's returning `True` or `False`, meaning you're not actually checking just one result, but two. Your while loop doesn't seem to have any end conditions either. Also your loop variable doesn't exist so your script throws an error. Lastly, `overalls` was unnecessary from what I could tell, since `iterations` kept track of that number anyway. Here's how I think the last section should look:

```
while iterations < 10:
    iterations += 1
    result = hundred()
    
    if result:
        number_of_true += 1

print(number_of_true, iterations)
```

When running the script, it either gives `10 10` or `0 10`, which I'm not sure is what you want, but at least the loop part is correct. If you're having a problem with `hundred()` then I suggest asking another question about that specifically. I think the issue with it is due to you using too many globals, some of which need resetting each time you call the function.

Comment: Yes, if we call it 10 times, I would like it to be printing 7 10, instead of 0 10  or 10 10... really stuck how to count Boolean returns. If I just keep calling the function alone, and on paper write down Trues and Falses, I get the correct answer. But I can't figure out how to count them up with a code.

Comment: You just increment a different variable, preferably a dict `count = {}`. Then you could simply write `count[hundred()] += 1`.

Comment: I am not familiar with dictionaries yet. I will trial and error with your suggestion.

Comment: The `dict` is probably the most important built-in type in Python. I'm not really exaggerating when I say, stop whatever you are doing and learn how they work ASAP. Trying to work around them is just a waste of time.